# pandas value_count() is showing different values every time I restart the notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Every time that I restart my `jupyter-lab` notebook, `value_count()` is showing different values.

```
bid = customers['BasketID']
bid.value_counts()
```

Here's the results of two executions:

```
576339     542
573585     535
579196     533
580727     529
578270     442
          ... 
563453       1
C567706      1
548001       1
C546895      1
574519       1
Name: BasketID, Length: 24627, dtype: int64



576339     542
573585     535
579196     533
580727     529
578270     442
          ... 
C562808      1
575205       1
549004       1
C542991      1
565577       1
Name: BasketID, Length: 24627, dtype: int64
```

As you can see there are always different numbers starting with a letter.

Since in the notebook I have to reference one of these numbers, I can't have it changing at every iteration.

Is there a way to make the method's output deterministic?

I guess that this weird behaviour is due to the sorting algorithm used by the method. Maybe there is a way to see/set the seed for the random number generator used by the algorithm?

Comment: Maybe all of such 'C'-codes have count 1? It seems that there are very few of them, can you look into `df[df['BasketId'].str.startswith('C')]` to get the full list of such items.

Comment: Instead of worrying about the order its stored in, why can't you get the associated value via `.loc`? `bid.value_counts().loc["C567706"]`

Comment: @CameronRiddell because it's not what I need. What I need is to show that there are non numerical values in the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value_counts` by default has `sort=True`, which most likely uses quicksort to sort. You can try to disable that with `sort=False`, which returns the series with sorted index:

```
bid.value_counts(sort=False)
```

If you still want the sorted series, you can sort manually with `sort_values` and use the stable `mergesort` method:

```
bid.value_counts(sort=False).sort_values(ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
```